# MediaHistory NowPlaying vs WriteRecentPlay

Tags: windows-phone-7, media-player

Is it necessary to call [`WriteRecentPlay`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.mediahistory.writerecentplay%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) in addition to assigning a [`NowPlaying`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.devices.mediahistory.nowplaying%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) value or does the latter imply the former as far as the OS handles it?

If it is required, can `WriteRecentPlay` be called at the same time as the `NowPlaying` assignment or should it be called when the audio completes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering that the certifications [call for separate image dimensions for now playing vs recent play](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff769558%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), it follows that two separate calls need to be made.